# MongoDB count by date AND to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I have a User table with "created" date field. Now I want to know how many new users were created on each day last week, as well as the total users by the end of each day (since the beginning of time).

For example:

```
{
  {
    day: 27,
    new_users: 5,
    total_users: 100
  }, {
    day: 28,
    new_users: 7,
    total_users: 107
  }, {
    day: 29,
    new_users: 2,
    total_users: 109
  }
}
```

I already got the new_users part by using simple grouping and summing. Code below is mongoid/Ruby.

```
    results = User.collection.aggregate(
    [{
      "$match" => {
          created: { "$gte" => 1.week.ago.beginning_of_day, "$lte" => Time.now }
        }
    },
    {
      "$group" => {
        _id: {
          year_joined: { "$year" => "$created" },
          month_joined: { "$month" => "$created" },
          day_joined: { "$dayOfMonth" => "$created" }
        },
        count: { "$sum" => 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      "$sort" => {"_id.year_joined" => 1, "_id.month_joined" => 1, "_id.day_joined" => 1}
    }]
  )
```

How do I also get the total_users in the results?

Comment: (1) Can you please show us what you have tried? We don't want to write all the code for you. (2) when you say total users, do you mean total users since the begining of time or since the beginning of last week?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg since the beginning of time. I've edited my question to include code.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close with your attempt. One thing is that since you're starting out by filtering down to own the last week, you don't need to care about the year or month.

Note: I don't know ruby, so I wrote it as I would in the mongo shell.

```
{
  "$match" => {
      created: { "$gte" => 1.week.ago.beginning_of_day, "$lte" => Time.now }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {"$dayOfMonth": "$created" },
        day: {"$dayOfMonth": "$created" },
        newUsers: { "$sum": 1}
    }
},
{
      "$sort" => {"_id.year_joined" => 1, "_id.month_joined" => 1, "_id.day_joined" => 1}
}
```

That will get you the `day` and `newUsers`, but it wont get you the total. I don't actually that is possible in a single query. One alternative might be to give each user a unique number and just take the max of the numbers for that day.

Comment: You're right about not needing year and month. Actually this snippet is meant to be generic so I can enter an arbitrary range of dates. The question was simplified to avoid distractions :) As for total_users, I'll give it another hour and report back.